# Why won't the .focus() method work for my sign-up page?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm currently designing a sign up page, with text next to the fields that changes depending on which input the user has selected.

```
$(function() {
  $('input').on('change', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val().length) {
      input.addClass('populated');
    } else {
      input.removeClass('populated');
    }
  });
});
$(".namewrapper").click(function() {
  $("#fname").focusin();
});
$("#fname").focusin(function() {
  $(".signup").fadeOut(200, function() {
    $(".signup").text("Phase 1");
    $(".introduction").fadeOut(200, function() {
      $(".introduction").text("To start, go ahead and enter your name.");
    });
    $(".signup").fadeIn(200);
    $(".introduction").fadeIn(200);
  });
});
$(".usernamewrapper").click(function() {
  $("#username").focus();
});
$("#username").focus(function() {
  $(".signup").fadeOut(200, function() {
    $(".signup").text("Phase 2");
    $(".introduction").fadeOut(200, function() {
      $(".introduction").text("Now, what would you like your username to be?");
      $(".introduction").fadeIn(200);
    });
    $(".signup").fadeIn(200);
  });
});
$(".emailwrapper").click(function() {
  $("#emailfield").focus();
});
$("#emailfield").focus(function() {
  $(".signup").fadeOut(200, function() {
    $(".signup").text("Phase 3");
    $(".introduction").fadeOut(200, function() {
      $(".introduction").text("What email shall we use?");
      $(".introduction").fadeIn(200);
    });
    $(".signup").fadeIn(200);
  });
});
$(".password1wrapper").click(function() {
  $("#password1").focus();
});
$("#password1").focus(function() {
  $(".signup").fadeOut(200, function() {
    $(".signup").text("Phase 4");
    $(".introduction").fadeOut(200, function() {
      $(".introduction").text("Make sure your password is rememberable and isn't short!");
      $(“.introduction”).append(“ < i class = “em em - key” > < /i>”);
            $(".introduction").fadeIn(200);
          });
        $(".signup").fadeIn(200);
      });
    });
    $(".password2wrapper").click(function() {
      $("#password2").focus();
    });
    $("#password2").focus(function() {
      $(".signup").fadeOut(200, function() {
        $(".signup").text("Phase 5");
          $(".introduction").fadeOut(200, function() {
            $(".introduction").text("Retype your password.");
            $(“.introduction”).append(“<i class=“em em-key”></i > ”);
      $(".introduction").fadeIn(200);
    });
    $(".signup").fadeIn(200);
  });
});
```

As you can see, depending on the field (or containing div) they select, the instructions change. This works fine when I only have the function for one field, but as soon as I add the functions for the rest of them, the instructions won't change. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You should have all your event bindings inside `$(function() { ... })`

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything @Barmar

Comment: You have some curly quotes instead of ASCII double quotes in your code: `$(“.introduction”).append(“ < i class = “em em - key” > < /i>”);`. Is that just a copying error, or is it in the real code? Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar even if it were copying error, OP would still need to escape the double quotes in the `="em em-key"` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out from console, turns out it wasn't processing the .append() functions correctly. After removing those, I found there were extra closing statements at the end of the file.